# WP7: Remove Underscore in application name

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a Windows Phone 7 app that has a space in the name. VS replaced the space with an underscore throughout the app, which is Ok for namespaces and such, but I cannot figure out how to remove it from the app name as it appars on the device start menu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the properties of your phone project and look for the Title property under Deployment Options.

Answer (score 0):

Double click on project properties and in the field xap file name remove underscore. It worked perfectly for me.